# Having a Function Inside of the Loop

Tags: functions, wp-query, loop, forms, plugin-gravity-forms

I am trying to make a frontend product editor for WooCommerce, and have a loop that returns all of the products for the current user. I am trying to use gravity forms as the editor, so a single gravity form is displayed and populated for each product. However, I am not sure how to handle naming the function so it is not being re-declared for every product.

```
global $current_user;
new WP_Query( array( 'author' => $current_user->ID, 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    add_filter('gfrom_pre_render_7', 'populate_each_product');
    function populate_each_product ($form){
        foreach($form["fields"] as &$field){
            if($field["id"] == 1){
                $field["defaultValue"] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_virtual', true);
            }
        }
        return $form;
    }
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Is there someway to add a counter or another variable to the function name? So along the lines of populate_each_product . `$post->ID ()` or something of that nature? I have looked around for this quite a bit, but found no reference of using functions inside loops so I am worried what I am trying to do is not possible

Comment: I've modified your question as there was no code indenting of any kind, and it was formatted poorly

Comment: Also **never** use `query_posts`

Comment: Thank you, I could definitely stand to improve a bit on my formatting, much appreciated

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that about the query_posts, took that off the wordpress codex - thanks

Comment: As useful as the codex is, anyone can edit it, and bad practices can worm their way in, so don't take it as gospel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before continuing, please read this:

http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012

It's by a core WordPress developer and you should consider it required reading. You should never use `query_posts`, and it's important to understand how to use loops correctly. That presentation will demonstrate the best practices, how, and why to use them.

I can see the approach you've taken, what you're trying to do is:

```
foreach post that's of type product that belongs to me
    add a function that fills in the default value for that post
```

Unfortunately, that filter is fired for all posts, not individual posts. Also your approach is using a named function, if it were javascript and you were using lambdas and it was a per post filter, e.g. 'gfrom_pre_render_'.$post->ID it might work, but that filter doesn't exist, and you're not using lambdas.

So instead, add your function to the filter, and it will get executed on all forms. Then filter out so that it only happens on the ones that you want:

```
add_filter('gfrom_pre_render_7', 'populate_each_product');
function populate_each_product ($form){
    global $post, $current_user;
    if($post->post_type == 'product' && $post->post_author == $current_user->ID){
        foreach($form["fields"] as &$field){
            if($field["id"] == 1){
                $field["defaultValue"] = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_virtual', true);
            }
         }
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Also this is how you would have done the query correctly:

```
$q = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => $current_user->ID, 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: After posting my question I realised that what your question needed was something different, so I rewrote most of it

Comment: Thanks for taking the time on that Tom, I am a little lost on the implementation of your code, I am probably just missing something. How should I tie the code in to the form? Should I include the form in the loop and the function in the functions.php file?

Comment: You don't need the loop at all, I only included it to demonstrate how it should have been written

Comment: and yes put the function in functions.php

Comment: Oh, that's the confusion then about concept and execution. Although I hadn't thought about it how you are doing it. I am trying to place this on a separate page, not on the product page. So in the user dashboard, it will pull a loop of products they have made and and display a copy of the form for each product, populated with the meta.

Comment: It will place it on any product whose author is you, instead place it prior to the loop you want it to apply to,and remove the filter afterwards

Comment: Okay, it seems like it is so close. It still won't pull the post ID in to the function. http://pastie.org/4830035 . I tested the function by displaying the_ID() then inserting it directly and it worked, but it won't pull it in to the function itself.

Comment: Okay, got it working. Thanks again for your help Tom

Comment: note the `global` statement

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the filter inside the loop. Put the code in `functions.php`, and use `get_posts` to get the products and populate the form.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this is essentially what we ended up doing above. Tom had just offered a more detailed answer. I still have not been able to pull the post ID from the loop on the page in to the function in the functions.php file